# How to read the large txt file and add data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to read a large data from a file of approx. 20MB to 50MB and then add its data into Postgres table. Below is the code that I have used but i am getting the error.

```
## test.txt##
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
a6
a7
a8
a9
```

### Code

```
using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
    {
        reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 10);

        // Import data array into table2
        using (var outStream =
            conn.BeginRawBinaryCopy("COPY veda_front_end.table3(field1) FROM STDIN binary"))
        {
            outStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }


    }
}
```

### Error

> 22P04: COPY file signature not recognized

I am not sure if I have written the right code. I am totally new to the file streaming and NpgSQL.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#raw-binary-copy) shows that after `STDIN` you might need to state `(FORMAT BINARY)`. And since you're copying from it, `STDOUT` is probably better... Though when I read about the copy function, it seems to be for the entire table - not a specific cell (column and row).

Comment: Why are you reading Test data with a binary reader?

Comment: You can connect to the database using oledb.  See connecitonstrings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/

Comment: @jdweng if you know another way to read the large file then, please help me with the code

Comment: You error has nothing to do with the size of the file.  Any of the stream read methods in Net should work.  You issue right now is you are not parsing the file correctly.  Do you really know the format if the data you are reading?  Reading one line at a time should work.  binary Reader does not have a ReadLine() method.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use raw binary COPY, which requires you to handle encoding/decoding for the PostgreSQL wire format... This is definitely not what you want.

The easiest way is to use [text COPY](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#text-copy), where you send your textual data directly, setting up the proper column delimiters (you seem to have none).

To get possibly better performance, you can use [binary COPY](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#binary-copy) (which isn't the same as *raw* binary COPY). This means you parse your file in C#, and then use an API to send your data to PostgreSQL. In this case, since your data is totally textual, you probably won't see a big difference with text COPY.

EDIT: It's also worth reading the [PostgreSQL docs on COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).